# What is the total geodesic curvature for the $S(u,v) = (\cos u,\sin u,v)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Say the curve $C(t) = (\cos(\pi t),\sin(\pi t),2t-t^2 )$ on the surface $S(u,v) = (\cos u,\sin u,v)$.
Find $\int_C \kappa_g ds$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2.$  (Here  $\kappa_g$ is the  the geodesic curvature of the $C$).

I'm trying to solve by Gauss bonnet theorem. $\int\int_M K dS + \int_C \kappa_g ds = 2\pi\chi(M)$ $-$(sum of the exterior angles).

Clearly $K = 0$ for the $S(u,v)$.  I took the area $M$ enclosed by the closed curve $C$ on $S$. In my thought, the area $M$ on $S(u,v)$ is homeomorphic with the plane figure(e.x. circle etc) , so $\chi(M)=1$ (Here   $\chi(M)$ is the Euler Characteristic). I added the picture of it at the first down in this post. The $M$ is enclosed by the black curve. We can get $\epsilon$ ,exterior angle of the $C$, by inner-product for the $C'(0)$ and $C'(2)$. So $\cos(\epsilon) = \frac{\pi^2 -4}{\pi^2+4}$.

Therefore, $\int_C \kappa_g ds = 2\pi-\arccos\left(\frac{\pi^2 -4}{\pi^2+4}\right)$.

But the answer was $-\arccos\left(\frac{\pi^2 -4}{\pi^2+4}\right)$. The answer's solution took the another curve $\beta(t) = S(t,2)$ and deduced $\chi(M) =0$. My question is I don't know the reason why my solution is false. Please help me.

P.s.
[image]

Comment: Your curves circle around the cylinder, and in itself it does not enclose any region.  It's not clear which elliptical area on $S$ you have in mind.

Comment: (You don't need to write "the" before a mathematical expression.)

Comment: @mr_e_man, oh Thank you. My English is really bad :)

Comment: The surface $S$ is a cylinder. That is missing in your picture.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your case $M$ and your black curve, The Euler Characteristic is $\chi(M)=0$. It is not $\chi(M)=1$ like your claim.

Why? ) The interior of the $M$ you've taken is hollow. That is there are no points at all for your  $M$ enclosed by the black curve.

Moreover there isn't boundary for your $M$. In other words, $C$ is not the boundary of $M$. Consequently you can't apply formula you suggested at the first.